# Date format in textbox [ASP.NET]

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a grid which gets populate with data from my database. As part of my grid I have a view button which views the records in a modal form.

One of my records has a date. When the textbox in the modal form gets populated with the date it gets displayed like this: "2018/01/25 12:00:00 AM"

I want only the date to be displayed without the time. I have made sure that inside my SQL table that it is only date being saved and it is.

This is the column in my grid:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}" SortExpression="Date"/>
```

This is my textbox:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" placeholder="Date" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
txtDate.Text = Y.Date.ToShortDateString();
Text='<%#((DateTime)Bind("NewDate")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")%>'
Text='<%# Bind("JoinDate", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'
```

I tried writing javascript code and limit the characters but the time still shows on load.

I would like only the date to be shown in my textbox.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Textboxes have nothidn to do with SQL, unless you stored strings instead of dates. `I have made sure that inside my SQL table that it is only date being saved and it is.` What does that mean? Is the column's type `date`? `datetime` but you strip the time part? Or did you converted the date to a string?

Comment: It means that I have made sure that my program is not saving the time into SQL just incase.

Comment: In any case, you didn't post the code that loads the data or binds it. If you convert the date to a string at any point, or store a string in the database, the format string won't work because you *don't* have a date for it to format.

Comment: which doesn't explain anything. If the type is `date` or `datetime` the format string would work and you wouldn't have to worry. If it's `varchar` or `nvarchar`, you don't have a date at all, just a string that looks like a date and can't be formatted. Make sure your field uses a date type and that you *don't* convert it to a string while loading, eg with `ToString()` or storing it in a string property. You still haven't posted your code BTW

Comment: The type is date

Answer (score 0):

change your grid code to this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" SortExpression="Date"/>
```

There are three Ms in date format, just remove one M, the format will be `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}`

Comment: The reason for the 3 Ms is so that the Date can be displayed like this: 25/Jan/2018

However, I did try what you suggested and the time still gets displayed in the textbox on my modal form

Comment: I try `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>`, it works. I am not sure why it didn't work in your case...

Comment: I had to add this to my stored procedure in my select statement

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tb_Schedule.Date, 103) [Date]  Not only the date shows which is correct. Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert my date to a specific format in SQL.

I added this to my stored procedure in my select statement

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tb_Schedule.Date, 103) [Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>' ID="txtDate" runat="server" placeholder="Date" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to directly bind your data, then add to the TextBox:

```
Text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", Eval("JoinDate")) %>'
```

I assume you wish to have two-way communication if you are using textbox, so use Eval instead of Bind.